# Cannot connect to VRDE session

Tags: linux, virtualbox, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm trying to connect to a headless virtual machine, but the connection keeps on being closed:

```
$ rdesktop 192.168.1.8:5012
Autoselected keyboard map en-us
ERROR: Connection closed
```

`VRDE` seems to be enabled (as reported by `VBoxManage showvminfo`):

```
VRDE:            enabled (Address 192.168.1.8, Ports 5012, MultiConn: off, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)
VRDE port:       5012
```

The host is Arch Linux. This is the output of `VBoxManage list extpacks`:

```
Extension Packs: 2
Pack no. 0:   VNC
Version:      5.0.4_OSE
Revision:     102546
Edition:      
Description:  VNC plugin module
VRDE Module:  VBoxVNC
Usable:       true 
Why unusable: 

Pack no. 1:   Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack
Version:      5.0.4
Revision:     102546
Edition:      
Description:  USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 Host Controller, Host Webcam, VirtualBox RDP, PXE ROM, Disk Encryption.
VRDE Module:  VBoxVRDP
Usable:       true 
Why unusable:
```

Also, `192.168.1.8` is the IP address of the host.

Any idea why I cannot connect using `rdesktop`?

Comment: Have you installed on your VM a rdesktop server, like for instance xrdp? RDP is not native to Linux, which implies it is not installed by default. The native Linux way to open a session onto a Linux machine is `ssh`, but even in this case you must setup a server, if you want to connect into it.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, I don't think that an rdesktop server is needed on the guest. I'm under impression that the server is provided by VirtualBox itself (as I'm not connecting to the guest, I'm connecting to the VirtualBox console which shows me the guest).